# Does setup:upgrade command includes the reindexing commands in itself

Tags: magento2.3.2

In magento2 - **setup:upgrade** command which is generally very fast, is taking a lot of time which has made me to see it suspiciously.

Indexers are all set on update On Schedule and when **setup:upgrade** command reaches at **Magento_Indexer** module it takes a lot of time to get over it probably equals to the time when indexers are run from command line.

I know upgrade commands clears a lot of code generated folders of magneto but seems like indexers are also included in version 2.3.2

Any response is very helpful?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Recurring events for the indexer module:

1. [Recurring schema event](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Indexer/Setup/Recurring.php) - which checks for new indexers to add them to the indexer grid
2. [Recurring data event](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Indexer/Setup/RecurringData.php) - event that calls the unsubscribe & subscribe method of the mview.

   From what is can see in the code, the *unsubscribe* method removes the triggers added to the db the the indexer is changed to **Update on schedule** and the *subscribe* adds the triggers back.

The subscribe/unsubscribe methods are defined in the [Magento/Framework/Mview/View.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mview/View.php) file, which will call the crate/remove methods from the [Magento/Framework/Mview/View/Subscription.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mview/View/Subscription.php)